# How can I fix this problem of the timing of printing?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, frequency

I am using Raspberry pi 3b+ and 4. I want to acquire accelerations at different sampling frequencies. Based on my code, I have set a compensation time "Error time" as will be shown in my code. The problem when increasing the sampling frequencies the compensation time is greater than (1/sampling frequency) which will give a negative time, which is not possible. Can you suggest me a solution to this problem?

```
ts = 1 / sampling_frequency

timeout_start = time.time()

while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
    start_time = time.time()
    x, y, z = accel.read()
    tuple = x, y, z
    value = [i / 256 for i in tuple]
    outputfile.write("{} ,{},{}\n".format(value[0], value[1], value[2]))
    end_time = time.time()
    time_elapsed = (end_time - start_time)
    time.sleep(ts - time_elapsed)
```

Comment: Obviously, the error is the negative time which will be the last line 
time.sleep(ts - time_elapsed)

Comment: You can try to use `linuxfd` module to work with high resolution timers. see: https://github.com/FrankAbelbeck/linuxfd/blob/master/examples/test_linuxfd.py#L65 for example.

Comment: Beware that Linux isn't a real-time operating system - you'll get randomish delays of varying times up to maybe tens of milliseconds during context switch, I/O, etc. which will impact the stability of your sampling

Comment: in fact those uncontrollable jitters may account for the occasional 'negative time' - you won't be able to fix that with any amount of performance-improving recoding because it's a feature of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going negative that means the current code is not performant enough to sample at that rate.

One improvement to speed it up could be to batch write to the file once completed. Try the following code and see if it's improved...

```
ts = 1 / sampling_frequency
timeout_start = time.time()
data = []

while time.time() < (timeout_start + timeout):
    start_time = time.time()
    data.append(accel.read())
    end_time = time.time()
    time_elapsed = end_time - start_time
    time.sleep(ts - time_elapsed)

for tple in data:
    values = [i / 256 for i in tple]
    outputfile.write(f"{values[0]} ,{values[1]},{values[2]}\n")
```

Comment: Thank you-- Unfortunately it didn't work and I am still having the same problem, "Negative time length"